# Undefined variable using function into function

Tags: php

I have an issue using this code in order to get the appropriate result.

My code:

```
function check_txt($url, $content) {
    global $content;
    $result = get_file_contents($url);

    $arr = array_filter($result, function($ar) {
       return ($ar['txt'] == $content);
    });

    return $arr[0];
}
```

I got this error when I execute the code:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: content in myfile.php
```

My question is how to pass content variable to `function($ar)` ? already tried `function($ar, $content)` and too `global $content;` like the code I posted.

Comment: `$content` is not in scope of anonymous function. You can use `use` in this case.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to USE the `$content` variable assuming it is actually available, to make it available in your annonymous function

```
function check_txt($url, $content) {

    $result = get_file_contents($url);

    $arr = array_filter($result, function($ar) use ($content) {
       return ($ar['txt'] == $content);
    });

    return $arr[0];
}
```

> The [Manual has more details and examples](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-203)

Answer (score 0):

Either
A) if you have $content previously defined in global scope, use the global you have and remove the $content parameter.
or,
B) remove the global declaration and pass something in using the $content parameter.

PS: As others have pointed out, you need to use a use() on the anon function... but also pass param or go global, don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

The array_filter() function filters the values of an array using a callback function.

This function passes each value of the input array to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_filter.asp

Hope this helps :)